# How to permanently remove system folders such as pictures, music, videos

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server

I found how to remove the braindead folders music, pictures, videos etc. from "This PC" (in my case Windows 2012 R2) via registry, see [Removing Desktop, Documents, Downloads, Music, Pictures, and Videos Folders from Navigation Pane](http://carlwebster.com/removing-desktop-documents-downloads-music-pictures-and-videos-folders-from-navigation-pane/).

This works, also removing "Libraries" altogether.

So far, so good, but I fail to remove the folders C:\Users\Administrator\Music etc. Once deleted, they come back after a few minutes. How can I get rid of them for good?

Thanks for your advice!

pi

Comment: First of all, welcome to Super User!  That being said, you probably see that because it is the built-in default `Administrator` account, so it will behave a bit differently.  For example, UAC is automatically off just for that specific account, but no others.  We are always glad to help, but is it really that crucial that you *don't* see those folders?

Comment: One trick is to delete the folder and create a read-only, hidden, system **file** with the same name. There may be smarter ways, but this has survived through several OS upgrades, when a lot of registry settings are recreated.

Comment: Thanks for the warm welcome, @Run5k. Crucial not because things wouldn't work otherwise, but because of a clear and clean folder structure. You simply see more if not that many folder clutter the folder tree.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, @AFH. I am surprised, there would be no key in the registry to simply deactivate them. I will give it a try.

Comment: I tried it, but it does not work out. Maybe I did something wrong. @AFH, you said system file. Is that a special file type? I just have normal empty files which I make read only and hidden. 

Now the funny things happens: In the folder list on the left in Windows Explorer I see all those files with a white icon, on the right side they are hidden, only Pictures remains visible.

I would like to attach a screenshot, not possible?

Comment: You will see the files in the parent directory, but they won't appear in your folder list. You can set the system attribute from `cmd` with the `attrib` command.

Comment: Thanks for that, @AFH. Now it remains to hide them in the navigation pane.

Comment: They shouldn't be there: the navigation pane normally shows only folders, and these are now files, not folders.

Comment: It looks like those super special and hard coded (?) folders are so permanent in Windows you cannot get them out of the folder list. Such a pain if you have to find your files in between garbage:-( Any ideas how to avoid it?

Comment: Really no idea?

Comment: Nearly 7 years later and Microsoft is still penetrating users with their "idea" of file organisation... :|